# C++ error trying to bind function to lua

Tags: c++, c, lua

**I think I found an answer, will return with results soon**

I get this error and have no idea how to fix it while not having the methods be static. If they are static I don't get the error but then I'm not able to use any of my non static variables or functions. Also before you say it may be that int and lua_CFunction are different types they aren't. Here is how lua_CFunction is defined

```
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);
```

*

```
1   IntelliSense: argument of type "int (LuckyIrc::*)(lua_State *l)" is incompatible with parameter of type "lua_CFunction" f:\Programming\Visual Studio\C++\IrcBot\IrcBot\LuckyIrc.h   129 4   IrcBot
```

Code:

```
class MyClass{
//other stuff
private:
//other stuff
    int Lua_SendMessage(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_SendRaw(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_SendAction(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_SendNotice(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_Quit(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_Part(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_SendNick(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_Kick(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_Join(lua_State *l);
    int Lua_Connect(lua_State *l);

    void SetUpLua()
    {
        LuaState = luaL_newstate();
        luaL_openlibs(LuaState);
        /*Error happens here*/lua_register(LuaState, "SendMessage", Lua_SendMessage);
        /*And here*/lua_register(LuaState, "SendRaw", Lua_SendRaw);
        /*And here*/lua_register(LuaState, "Quit", Lua_Quit);
        /*And here*/llua_register(LuaState, "Part", Lua_Part);
        /*And here*/lua_register(LuaState, "SendNotice", Lua_SendNotice);
        /*And here*/lua_register(LuaState, "SendAction", Lua_SendAction);
        /*And here*/llua_register(LuaState, "SetNick", Lua_SendNick);
        /*And here*/llua_register(LuaState, "Join", Lua_Join);
        /*And here*/llua_register(LuaState, "Kick", Lua_Kick);
        /*And here*/llua_register(LuaState, "Connect", Lua_Connect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`lua_register` only directly supports free functions (or static methods, which are the same except for the visibility). So, you'll have to find another way to pass around your object pointer. If you just need a singleton (i.e. you want to share the same state for all calls of your script functions), the easiest way would be a private static variable (instance pointer).

Also, you could try using luabind library for much easier binding of custom functions and classes.

Comment: Alright thanks for the information. I think I found a way to solve the problem using the function class.